# iPad App using ActionSheet showing fromRect which doesn't show correctly until the device is rotated at least once

Tags: ipad, ios4, orientation, uiactionsheet, uidevice

I have an iPad app, which has a action sheet called from a button. Im using the showFromRect for the actionSheet so it looks like a popOver.  When the app first starts up the actionSheet never shows in the correct place until after the device is rotated at least once. After the device is rotated the actionSheet is in the correct place. my code is below.

```
-(IBAction)showMenu
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy To The Clipboard" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Term & Definition",@"Term",@"Definition", nil];

UIDevice *thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
CGRect myImageRect;

if(thisDevice.orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 950.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"P");}  //Portait Mode
else if(thisDevice.orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 950.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"PUD");}//Portait Mode UpsideDown
else if(thisDevice.orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 700.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"LL");}//Landscape Mode Left
else if(thisDevice.orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 700.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"LR");}//Landscape Mode Right

[actionSheet showFromRect:myImageRect inView:self.view animated:YES];
[actionSheet release];
}
```

any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: first off UIDeviceOrientation  is different from UIInterfaceOrientation. the left and right orientations are flipped so that when the home button is on the left it's in UIInterfaceOrientationLeft, but also in UIDeviceOrientationRight.

Comment: secondly, if the rect is being drawn in the current view then it will be drawn in that view's coordinate system. So if the view isn't full screen it might not show up where you expect.

Comment: after the device rotates once it shows up where it is expected. see below for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)pasteMenuiPad
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy To The Clipboard" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Term & Definition",@"Term",@"Definition", nil];

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 950.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);;

    if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 950.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"P");}    //Portait Mode
    else if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 950.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"PUD");}//Portait Mode UpsideDown
    else if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 700.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"LL");}//Landscape Mode Left
    else if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){myImageRect = CGRectMake(300.0f, 700.0f, 320.0f, 175.0f);NSLog(@"LR");}//Landscape Mode Right

    [actionSheet showFromRect:myImageRect inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

This method shows the correct positioning whether or not the device has been rotated.